# Can I stay in Bulgaria after divorce with a change in my residence status?

Tags: working-visas, resident-permit, bulgaria

I am from Morocco, and I married a Bulgarian woman in 2014. After I joined her in Bulgaria, I got a 1-year family residence permit, which I then renewed for another year. It will expire in June.

My wife now wants a divorce. After the divorce, will I be able to renew the residence permit again? Can I apply for a work permit and residence after the divorce? I am already working under contract for a company.